# I want to show that $x^2 - x + C\epsilon\ge 0$ under some assumption.

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Let $x\ge 0$. For sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, assume that the property $x\le \sqrt\epsilon$ implies $x\le \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Then I want to show that $$x^2 - x + C\epsilon\ge 0 $$
for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ and some positive constant $C$(does not depend on epsilon).

Comment: $x\leq\sqrt{\epsilon}$ does not imply $x\leq\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Furthermore it is trivial, that for any $x \in \mathbb R$ and any $\varepsilon >0$, you can pick $C$ large enough, such that $x^2-x+C\varepsilon >0$...

Comment: @MrYouMath Thanks I mean in the case that we assume that argument for sufficiently small epsilon

Comment: @MooS Then C depends on epsilon? How about the case that C does not depend on epsilon and x

Comment: The implication is still wrong for small epsilons

Comment: Of course $C$ has to depend on $\varepsilon$...

Comment: Yes but the question is if I assume the implication, the argument holds or not

Comment: You have $x^2-x\ge -x$. So if $x\le\epsilon$, then $x^2-x+\epsilon\ge 0$. Is that what you are trying to establish? (ie you can take $C=1$).

Comment: @almagest thanks, but I want to remove your assumption $x\le\epsilon$ by using the implication above(the first line)

Comment: @Keverta You have $x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}\ge0$ for all $x$. Moreover you have equality for $x=\frac{1}{2}$. So if you are happy with $C$ depending on $\epsilon$, then that is easy, just take $C$ so that $C\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$. If you want $C$ independent of $\epsilon$, then it is not possible.

Comment: "Let $x\ge 0$. For sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, assume that $x\le \sqrt\epsilon$." That does not make sense. Given $x$ you have to make $\epsilon$ sufficiently large, to make $\sqrt\epsilon$ greater than $x$, not to make it sufficiently small. Or maybe you want to say only "Assume that $x\le \sqrt\epsilon$"

Comment: @miracle173 somebody edited my original argument. Now it has fixed. I mean we assume the property that $x\le \sqrt\epsilon$ implies $x \le 1/2 \sqrt\epsilon$

Comment: the implication is false

Comment: That sentence make no sense. If yo want to assume that  $x \le 1/2 \sqrt\epsilon$ then assume it. But again, your formulation does not make no sense.

Comment: @miracle173 I do not assume $x\le 1/2\sqrt\epsilon$. I assumed that the argument "If $x\le\sqrt\epsilon$ then $x\le 1/2 \sqrt\epsilon$"

Comment: if $x=5$ what is your sufficiently small $\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roots of your polynomial are:

$$x_1 = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4C\varepsilon}}{2}, x_2 = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4C\varepsilon}}{2}.$$

If $\varepsilon > \frac{1}{4C}$, you have two complex conjugate roots and 
$x^2 - x + C\epsilon > 0 ~\forall x$. But in this case $\varepsilon$ is not sufficiently small.

If $\varepsilon \leq \frac{1}{4C}$, you have two real roots and

$$x^2 - x + C\epsilon\ge 0 ~\text{iff}~ x \leq x_1 \wedge x \geq x_2.$$

Notice also that if both $C$ and $\varepsilon$ are positive, then $x_1 \geq 0$ and $x_2 > 0$. In particular, $x_1 \in \left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right]$ for $\varepsilon \in \left[0, \frac{1}{4C}\right]$.

We want that 
$$x_1 > \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\varepsilon}.$$

Anyway, $x_1 \leq \frac{1}{2}$, and hence:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\varepsilon} < x_1 \leq \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow\sqrt{\varepsilon} < 1 \Rightarrow 0 < \varepsilon < 1.$$

This must satisfied together with $\varepsilon \leq \frac{1}{4C}$ and hence

$$\frac{1}{4C} < 1 \Rightarrow C > \frac{1}{4}.$$

Finally:

$$x^2 - x + C\epsilon\ge 0 ~\forall 0 < x < \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\varepsilon} ~\text{iff}~ C > \frac{1}{4} ~\text{and}~ 0<\varepsilon<\frac{1}{4C}.$$